# How to find asynchronous Location header response PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, request, location, response

I am sending json data as part of post request to the specified target url and able to get the Location url. But the response from the target url is asynchronous response. So how to find and when to call the Location url to get the response. Below is my code to get the Location url.

```
$target_url = 'http://websieapi.com/api/messaging/post';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //include headers in http data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$json_request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = substr($result, 0, $curl_info["header_size"]); //split out header
preg_match("!\r\n(?:Location|URI): *(.*?) *\r\n!", $headers, $matches);
$location_url = $matches[1];
curl_close($ch);
```

Now in my $location_url, I am having generated url. But how do I know when to call this url to get the response. Because if there is high traffic then it will take time to generate response. Is there any way to find if the response has been generated or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think `response from the target url is asynchronous`? It's not.

Comment: Because when I pass the Location url in another curl call I am not getting data, I will take 5 to 10 sec time depending upon the queue size.

Comment: You are mixing up asynchronous requests with a completely different problem. cURL requests aren't async. In fact, all requests in HTTP/1.x are synchronous. What makes AJAX async for example is the way the JS engine handles them and lets other code execute while it's waiting for the response. What you are dealing with here is completely up to the owner of that API and has nothing to do with cURL or PHP or async. If it takes time for a resource to become available after you requested it, you need to consult the documentation of the API to find out if there's any way to e.g. poll it.

Comment: Unsure what you mean exactly, but maybe `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` could be useful for you? Find it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Thank you, I will go with Ajax call .